# Does Nagelring Proc with Zunimasa 6 set bonus?

Tags: diablo-iii

Nagelring do big damage. I've heard it does 10000% or 100x damage.

Zunimasa bonus makes our pet do 1500% damage or 15 times damage.

Does that mean that nagelring + Zunimasa full set will do a whoping 1500 times damage?

Let's see.

If my damage is 1 million, I will do 1.5 billion damage.

Just want to make sure if my calculation is right?

Answer (score 1):

It does not. Zunimassa's effect is specific to the Witch Doctor's summoned pets.

Comment: you sure? source?

Comment: 100% Sure. A quick search on the subject brings me to an [unnofficial wiki](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Zunimassa's_Haunt) which while it's not a completely reliable source, provides the same information.

Comment: The source would be no one is using the combination you suggested. It just can't reasonably be that nobody of people playing full-time and pushing rifts we here can only dream of, didn't try something that obvious. "Try" not as in "have an idea" but "pull out a set of perfect Ancients and test".

Comment: and yet http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Belt_of_Transcendence works with zunimasa bonus